# pass a static value to a controller from routes in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.3

i would like to pass a static value(variable or a static string) from route definition to a controller.
for example if consider the following route:

```
Route::get('/', [
      'uses' => '\Controllers\FoController@show',
      'as' => 'show'
]);
```

i want to pass a variable(ex, $var1) to that, and then can access to that in the FoController constructor or other controller methods , so i don't like that variable's value shows in the url.
how can i do this? thanks...

Comment: If you want the value to be static, why don't you use that value in the controller's function itself ? Can you please explain your question?

Comment: what himashu is said true, if u want to pass static variable, and dont want to show in the url as well why not using it inside controller

Answer (score 3):

as a follow up to @serge answer you can do it also this way just posting maybe it will be useful to someone

```
Route::get('/','fooController@index')
    ->defaults('id', '3');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a closure and call the controller yourself and pass what ever you want..

```
Route::get('/', function(){
  $controller = app()->make('FoController');
  return $controller->callAction('show', ['foo' => 'bar', 'ping' => 'pong']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.

```
Route::any('/home/createuser/{id}','HomeController@createuser');
```

you can use {} operator for parameters.
in controller.

```
public function createuser($id){
//here you can use $id
}
```

Comment: It is bad to just mark answer as none useful without showing why. I just mark it useful as reverse.